# Rendering the view on uitableviewcell when viewcontroller is shown again

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let documentPartCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("documentPartCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DocumentPartCell
                documentPartCell.documentPart = documentPart
    return documentPartCell 
    }
```

And here is my cell class:

```
class DocumentPartCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var documentPartProgress: UILabel!
    var allFields: Int
    var invalidFields: Int
    var documentPart: DocumentPart? {
        didSet {
self.documentPartProgress.text = "\(Int(allFields)! - Int(invalidFields)!) / \(allFields)"
}
```

Basically, `documentPartProgress` label shows the progress of document. The flow of my app is that there is a cell which shows progress in VC1. When the cell is pressed, it moves to VC2 and you can make changes. When you answer questions the progress changes. When you press `back` button in VC2, it goes back to VC1 and should update `documentPartProgress`. But it doesn't. How can I update the view on UITableViewCell when back button in VC2 is pressed?

Ex) 
Expectation: before changes -> 3/5. After changes -> 4/5

Reality: before changes -> 3/5. After changes -> 3/5

the progress label text does not change.

Comment: After coming back to VC1 from VC2 , where is the code to reload the specific cell , you must reload it by delegate or notification... or writing the reload code in viewDidAppear().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to put `yourTableView.reloadData()` in `viewWillAppear()` instead of `viewDidLoad()`

**Note**, I suppose you already updated the dataSource array. If you didn't update the dataSource, then you need to update it by using delegate or posting notification.

let me know if this is the case, I will Update my answer for more details.

Comment: I've already done it. reloadData solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working over several view controllers, I would make variables associated with progress global (Define them before class). That should update it accurately throughout the project. (It may not be best practice, but it will get the job done)